# Вытащить часть из строки, заменить и засунуть обратно

Tags: preg_match, php

В общем, есть такая строка:

```
[mi]link1[/mi] [mt]text[/mt] [mi]link2[/mi] [mi]link3[/mi] [mt]text[/mt]
```

Нужно вытащить всё ссылки между тегами `[mi]`. Затем с ними производятся некоторые манипуляции, в результате получаем массив с новыми ссылками, например:

```
$mas = array('newlink1','newlink2','newlink3');
```

А затем нужно сохранить всё это дело назад в строку и получить:

```
[mi]newlink1[/mi] [mt]text[/mt] [mi]newlink2[/mi] [mi]newlink3[/mi] [mt]text[/mt]
```

Вот что написал:

```
$str = '[mi]link1[/mi] [mt]text[/mt] [mi]link2[/mi] [mi]link3[/mi] [mt]text[/mt]';
//вытаскиваем все ссылки из тегов
preg_match_all('#\[mi\](.+?)\[\/mi\]#is',$str,$result);
//вытащили, в $result[1] получили массив с ссылками
//...
//манипуляции с ссылками опущены, получен новый массив
$mas = array('_link1','_link2','_link3');
//теперь нужно заменить ссылки в тегах в исходной строке - как?
```

`preg\_replace`, как я понимаю, тут не поможет, `preg\_split` - тоже, ибо попробовал, берёт только первое значение из массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `$result` - это массив исходных ссылок:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++){
str_replace($result[$i], $mas[$i], $str);
}
```